# Should I use GDI+ or it can be done in a simple way

Tags: c#, gdi+, maps, coordinates

I have some business requirement where user uploads an image(map of a room or some place) into my application that gets stored into my database. When user uploads this picture it gives us its width and height of the image and could possibly also give us some points also within an image.

Now, we have some location tracking device in our application that tracks the location of anyone who holds some tag that are readable from this device at far locations.

This location has to be mapped on to the uploaded image. What are the possibilities to show this data on to that image. Lets say i got the coordinate where i have to show that Tag.

How will i show this.

Do i need to use GDI to mark that coordinate on that image ?

Comment: Is GDI+ not simple?  What would be simpler in a WinForms app?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are displaying that image in a PictureBox control. The simplest way to do would be GDI+. You just have to override OnPaint() method of your PictureBox and after your image is drawn, you can draw overlay shape or text of your tag.

Comment: Is it possible to paint that text or shape on that image and upon paint complete. I can save that image with added shapes and text for printing ?

Comment: Well if you want to save it, the first load your original image into Bitmap class and draw your tags on that bitmap then call save that bitmap. In this case you need to get the Graphics object from that bitmap to draw on bitmap. Something like "Graphics g =Graphics.FromImage(bitmapImage);"